The expression relating to bugs biting each other, causing them to move faster in a swarm
This may extend beyond the scope of this stack exchange. In some notes I am writing for a class, I identify that capitalism always demands growth since everyone is always competing to outdo one other.
However, I recall hearing an expression somewhere that relates to maybe gnats: they are in a swarm and it is technically a massive orgy, but when they fly in a swarm, the gnat behind is biting the one in front, and so thus creates a repeating chain of trying not to get over-taken by the other. I wanted to include this expression in the notes, but I could not find this expression anywhere online, so I assume I have it wrong. Was it a gnat, or was it something else?
EDIT
As noted in the comments, gnats do not bite. But in any case, the expression related to some short-lived bug in some fast moving swarm that moves fast because they are trying not to get eaten by the one behind them. Now that I think of it, it could have been locusts, since they are voracious eaters that suffer from a bug-like tragedy of the commons.

The closest I can think of is the expression "dog eat dog". But this just denotes the constant competition, not that it propels everything forward (often the opposite -- little gets done because of all the infighting).

The expression exemplified by say 'Arsenal are snapping at Liverpool's heels' is a metaphor conveying fierce competition as a strong motivational force. But no gnats involved. I will make this an answer if it is acceptable.

@EdwinAshworth I do remember an expression that involved some species of bug, however. How about we wait and see what others say on this?

I've never heard of insects in a swarm biting the one in front. (And is orgy really the word you meant?)

@KateBunting I searched up gnats and technically that is what they are doing in a swarm; I do not recall what bug it was that had its swarm propelled forward, and to be honest, that original analogy might have been wrong to begin with.

Oh, I see - you mean they swarm for mating purposes!

Gnats are not known for biting; there's no definitive definition of gnat (it's not a taxonomic category or clade) but some limit it to non-biting insects.

There's also the quip about not having to outrun the bear.

@StuartF After looking it up, I figured that out; thus, this post.

Can you re-phrase that, please?
'Bugs biting each other' and  'something causing bugs to move faster in a swarm' might each work separately but together? Never.

Perhaps you're thinking of this, which has become a nursery rhyme:
Quotations: Augustus De Morgan [MacTutor; University of St
Andrews]


Great fleas have little fleas upon their backs to bite 'em,
And little fleas have lesser fleas, and so ad infinitum....

[He was imitating:

So, naturalists observe, a flea
Has smaller fleas that on him prey;
And these have smaller still to bite 'em;
And so proceed ad infinitum.

Jonathan Swift: Poetry, a Rhapsody.]

Hall of People offers this transparent interpretation of the metaphorical usage:

HOME PROVERBS [prey]

Big fleas have little fleas upon their back to bite them, and little fleas have lesser fleas, and so ad infinitum.

means that:

Everyone is preyed upon by someone, who in turn has someone preying on him or her, and so on.



I suppose it was a flea, then?

Good one that. + 1
